# Error Compiling Flutter Flame Game in VSCode After Flame Version Upgrade

Tags: flutter, flame

After upgrading from Flame 1.0.0 to 1.3.0, my project stopped building with errors like so:

```
Error: Type 'HasHitboxes' not found.
package:project/…/sprite_components/player_component.dart:14
with HasGameRef, HasHitboxes, Collidable
```

The errors are related only to HitBoxes and Collidables, in that they are not found, I'm suspecting something needs importing in Flame 1.3.0.

These are my imports:

```
import 'package:flame/components.dart';
import 'package:flame/geometry.dart';
import 'package:flame/input.dart';
import 'package:flame/sprite.dart';
```

I tried:

```
flutter pub cache clean
flutter pub get
```

But no luck, is there anything else that needs doing?

P.S. If I downgrade back to 1.0.0, everything works fine.

Comment: After reading the 1.3.0 docs, I needed to add the `HasCollisionDetection` mixin to the `FlameGame` and `CollisionCallbacks` mixin to the `SpriteComponents`. Also, components like `HitboxCircle` are now known as `CircleHitbox`. `HasHitboxes` mixin is deprecated and not needed anymore.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`HasHitboxes` and `Collidable` aren't used anymore.

Hitboxes are now a first class component in Flame, so you just have to add the hitboxes directly to the component with `component.add`. If you want to listen for collisions with those hitboxes you have to add the `CollisionCallbacks` mixin to the component and the `HasCollisionDetection` to the game.

https://docs.flame-engine.org/1.3.0/flame/collision_detection.html